# bootstrap style conflicts with forms bound with models laravel 4

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, laravel-4

I am developing an application with laravel 4, I have forms that are filled with data from a model, in other words a model is bound to the form 
I need to add some bootstrap style to the form and I do it this way 
this is my view file:

```
 {{
  Form::model($user, array( $user->id))
 }}

{{ Form::label('last_name', 'Last Name') }}
{{ Form::text('last_name', '', array('class' => 'form-control')) }}

 {{ Form::close() }}
```

and this is my controller code:

```
   public function edit(){
      $user = User::find(Auth::user()->id); 
     return View::make('edit')->with('user',$user);
  }
```

The Issue:

As soon as I add this class to the form's element the  content of the form will disappear and no data is bound to it anymore, how should I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer the second argument of this

```
{{ Form::text('last_name', '', array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
```

is the input value of text field so it should be like this:

```
 {{ Form::text('last_name', $user->last_name, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
```